# Field Service Lightning Data Sync Issue

Tags: permissions, permission-sets, field-service-lightning, fieldservice, fsl

Please help me out. I am getting this error(mentioned in image below) on Field Service Lightning Mobile App. What could be the reason?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved. it was due to profile settings. i was using standard user profile for technician, then i cloned System Administrator profile and modify new profile according to my technician requirements.

Comment: It would be helpful for others with similar issues if you [edit] your answer to go into greater detail about what you did.

Comment: @DerekF sure i will update.